# Custon dialog in android -- without border and transparent BG

Tags: android, dialog

I want to do the following dialog - without a border and transparent BG:
I want to have shadows for the edittext and the image (like in flash popups in the web)

```
                    ------------------------
                    |                      |
                    |                      |shade
                    |  Edit text           |
                    |                      |
                    ------------------------
                  -------              shade
                  |Image| shade
                  -------
                    shade
```

Yoav

Comment: But how..... How do I make the shadows for the image and the edittext? I know how to do BG transparent and no border. For this I am using android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to make image for edittext and imageview with shadow and apply that image as background ..

see this image..

[image: shadow image]

Comment: and what about the imageview? How do I add a shade to it?

Comment: you can also use background of imageview